# Why do I get a 'macro parameter # in vertical mode' error?

Tags: macros, errors

I am trying to define a `new command` in the following manner:

```
\newcommand{\textbelow}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_\substack{#2}}
```

It looks like the underscore character `_` is creating the problem. If I remove it, I do not get any error, but that is not what I want to do.

The syntax is correct, because outside of `newcommand` it works fine.

```
\[\underbrace{Look Down}_{\substack{hello \\ world}}\]
```

Why am I not able to make a new command out of this? If it is not possible to write an underscore `_` inside `newcommand`, what is the workaround?

Thank you for your assistance.

---

If you so require, here is a full example of what I am trying to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\textbelow}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_\substack{#2}}
\newcommand{\test}[2]{\underbrace{#1}\substack{#2}}

\begin{document}

This \(\underbrace{Look Down}_{\substack{hello \\ world}}\) works fine.

But the newcommand does not:
    \[ \textbelow{Look Down}{hello \\ world} \]

\end{document}
```

---

### Edit:

@egreg's solution does not work for me. Here is a screenshot of the error I get in TeXstudio.

[image: error]

Comment: The syntax is *incorrect*: `\newcommand{\textbelow}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\substack{#2}}}` would be right.

Comment: That example ***surely*** doesn't produce the error.

Comment: @egreg I guess not. But would you terribly mind if I asked you to make a guess at why I might be getting the error? Could it be because of how I have structured my document (separate folders for packages, macros, chapters, main tex file etc.)?

Comment: Without a *real* example producing the error, it's impossible to say. Check your braces, not only in that definition.

Comment: @egreg I got it. Thanks for asking me to check the log file. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors I get are

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \vcenter 
l.12     \[ \textbelow{Look Down}{hello \\ world}
                                                  \]
? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.12 ...[ \textbelow{Look Down}{hello \\ world} \]
```

which clearly stem from the missing braces around `\substack{...}`.

Indeed, if I add the braces, the example code runs without problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\textbelow}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\substack{#2}}}

\begin{document}

This \(\underbrace{Look Down}_{\substack{hello \\ world}}\) works fine.

But the newcommand does not:
    \[ \textbelow{Look Down}{hello \\ world} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this doesn't seem good for typesetting *text*.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. Maybe there is something else I am not telling you, but I get an error even with your simple fix. Please check the screenshot I added to my question.

Comment: The “macro parameter in vertical mode” error usually means you have misplaced braces. Rather than the screenshot, please add the real error message you find in the `.log` file.

Comment: I tried copying and pasting the exact code from your answer to the page I am currently working on. I still get the error.